# Thieves' words for their victims

Tags: terminology, word-usage

What words might a thief (of any variety) use to describe the victims of his theft?

Con artists in film often use "mark", for example. Is there other jargon specific to the con branch* of crime? How about burglars? Muggers? Bank robbers? Politicians? Oh, sorry... Highwaymen? Pickpockets?

---

<sub>*We might call these words "con-specific". `:p`</sub>

Comment: "punters" can be used, although the people who refer to their customers that way might not like being called thieves - even when they are!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are many terms for victim of a thief or swindler besides mark. Among them are

- dupe
- stooge
- sucker
- fall guy
- chump
- patsy

In games like chess, witless victims of chess sharps are called "fish" or "patzers".

In poker, victims of the poker sharks are called, variously

- fish
- donkeys (or "donks")
- dead money
- whales (fools with a lot of money; you generally see sharks circling around these players in a feeding frenzy)

Comment: "Whales" was also the term used by the brokers in "Boiler Room" for their clients.

Comment: @jhocking: Yes, and it's been a gambling term for a long time. Casinos having been using it for decades to describe their high-roller clientele (rich people who want to impress people by dropping tens or hundreds of thousands of dollars at the tables).

Comment: Yeah I saw that in your answer, interesting tidbit.

Comment: BTW, I am tempted to suppose that "whale" derives from "fish" — a whale (to those unaware that a whale is a mammal) seeming like a big "fish".

Answer (score 3):

From the *thematic* [Oxford Dictionary of Slang](http://avaxhome.ws/ebooks/encyclopedia_dictionary/The_Oxford_Dictionary_of_Slang.html) by Lexicographer John Ayto (including the word *mark* you already mention).

For a simple **swindle**:

> **fly-flat** (1864) British, dated; applied to someone taken in by
>   confidence tricksters; from *fly*
>   (knowing, alert) + obsolete *flat*
>   (gullible person)
>   •  Joyce Cary: 'I
>   don't see why we should consider the
>   speculators.' 'A lot of fly-flats who
>   thought they could beat us at the
>   game.'(1938)

> **mark** (1883) Orig US; applied to the intended victim of confidence
>   tricksters; often in the phrase a soft
>   (or easy) mark
>   • Edmund McGirr: In
>   the twenties it was the Yanks who was
>   the suckers, but now... it's us who
>   are the marks. (1973)

For **kidnap** victims:

> **package** (1933) Mainly US; applied to a kidnap victim
>   • Sun
>   (Baltimore): The 'package', as the
>   kidnapped victim is called, is rushed
>   across the State line and delivered to
>   the'keepers'. (1933)

Comment: Kidnappers! Nice, I didn't even think of them.

Answer (score 1):

- Nigerian scammers: Mugu
- Politicians: voters